# Rewriting a logic in SQL Query

Tags: sql

There is one query in my stored procedure, like the following one:

```
SELECT .....
FROM .....
WHERE .....
AND
(
  @date_from IS NULL 
  OR (ahd.dealid IS NULL OR @date_from >= ahd.dealdf)
)
AND 
(
  @date_to IS NULL 
  OR (ahd.dealid IS NULL OR @date_to <= ahd.dealdt)
)
```

I am trying to rewrite like this:

```
SELECT .....
FROM .....
WHERE .....
AND
(
   (@date_from IS NULL AND @date_to IS NULL)
   OR
   (ahd.dealid IS NULL)
   OR 
   (
     (@date_from IS NOT NULL AND @date_from >= ahd.dealdf)
      AND
     (ahd.dealid IS NOT NULL AND @date_to <= ahd.dealdt)
   )
)
```

Is that correct based on the TRUE/FALSE logic?

Comment: Why are you re-writing it?  The original query made perfect logical sense and was easy to follow.  Even if the second query is logically equivalent, it hurts my head to try to follow it...

Comment: I need to add new condition in it, and keeping the original one will make the job complicated.

Comment: Well it's not equivalent just to let you know.  You can have date_from be an actual value and date_to be a null and have the original query work.  Yours unfortunately will not.  Yours is literally both have to be null or both have to be a value or dealid is null.

Comment: No this will not work..just think of a scenario where datefrom is not null, but dateto is null or vice-versa

Comment: You really should work with the original query since it is functional and easy to understand.  Your question really should relate to how to do your modification to the existing query.

Comment: You should consider using `COALESCE`.  For example `(COALESCE( @date_from,  ahd.dealdf - 1 day)  >= ahd.dealdf)` is more "robust" and easier to work with because you don't have to add in the check for non-null.

Comment: Thank you guys, and I will work on the original query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a simplification:

```
(
  1 OR 2 OR 3
)
AND 
(
  4 OR 2 OR 5
)
```

this is what you are looking at, so

```
2 OR ((1 OR 3) AND (4 OR 5))
```

is not the same as

```
(1 AND 4) OR 2 OR (3 AND 5)
```

The original logic would be true with 1 and 5 or 3 and 4 which is lost in the second variation.